# Are there infinitely many even integers $n$ such that $1+4\varphi(n)$ is a perfect square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\varphi(n)$ the Euler's totient function. The sequence of even integers $n$ such that $$1+4\varphi(n)$$ is a perfect square starts as $$4, 6, 14, 18, 26, 28, 36, 42, 44, 50\ldots$$

> **Question.** I've curiosity about this question: are there infinitely many even integers $n$ such that $1+4\varphi(n)$ is a perfect square? **Many thanks.**

Comment: If an odd integer $n$ gives a square, then $2n$ does the same. All because in that case $\phi(2n)=\phi(n)$. Therefore the assumption that $n$ should be even is kinda unnecessary.

Comment: Then perfect, many thanks for your claims @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Let $p>2$ be a prime. Then $\phi(2p^2)=p(p-1)$ and thus
$$
1+4\phi(2p^2)=1+4p(p-1)=(2p-1)^2.
$$

Comment: Very quick, many thanks then.

Comment: The fact that $(2n+1)^2=4n(n+1)+1$ came in handy many times when I was (35+ years ago) in IMO-training. Just trying to match that pattern. Controlling $\phi(n)$ is easier when $n$ has only a few prime factors.

Comment: Many thanks for your tricks.